How to store and view variable in array using php
How to store and view variable in an array? Below is my php code
$url = 'https://www.connect.inspay.in//v3/money/search_beneficiary?token='.$token.'&username='.$user_name.'&sender_number='.$number.'';
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
echo $xml;

This is my result, but I need the values stored in a variable and to view them:
{"status":"Success","message":"Bene fetched from DB","data":[{"bene_id":"9578018305","bankid":"SBIN0012772","bankname":"Thiyagarajan","name":"Thiyagarajan","accno":"37707925421","ifsc":"SBIN0012772","verified":"Y","banktype":"ALL","paytm":true}]}


I don't know why you called your variable $xml when it clearly contains JSON?? Always use meaningful variable names then you don't confuse yourself when you have to read your code back, or debug it. It also helps not to confuse others who might need to read it!

Anyway, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-to-extract-and-access-data-from-json-with-php will teach you everything you need to know about processing JSON data in PHP, and accessing it. Always please try to do some basic research before posting a question. See also [ask].
